# Can you wait for user response message with bwmarrin/discordgo?

Tags: go, discord

Is there any option to wait for user response message in discordgo? I'm looking for something similar to discord.js awaitMessages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but you can make a collection that holds message and event information and checking news messages.

Simply

1. Make a collection/array
2. Add message information
3. Check if the incoming message in the message event handler is in the collection
4. Handle event
5. Remove from collection

Don't forget set a timeout and clear expired data from collection.

Answer (score 0):

according the docs: [awaitMessages](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#basic-message-collector)

> time: Amount of time in milliseconds the collector should run for
>
> max: Number of messages to successfully pass the filter

---

In Go, you can easily use a routine with just one keyword `go`, so implementing asynchronous (`async`) is very simple.

---

#### solving ideas:

1. Create a [message storage center](https://gist.github.com/CarsonSlovoka/395ec4218aa406d1ef59066a8ac0e909#file-awaitmessages-go-L36): It has the following features:

   - [store all sent messages](https://gist.github.com/CarsonSlovoka/395ec4218aa406d1ef59066a8ac0e909#file-awaitmessages-go-L37)
   - Have a [garbage collection](https://gist.github.com/CarsonSlovoka/395ec4218aa406d1ef59066a8ac0e909#file-awaitmessages-go-L63-L89) mechanism: Since we are constantly collecting messages, we need a mechanism to eliminate old messages.
   - Need a [mutex](https://gist.github.com/CarsonSlovoka/395ec4218aa406d1ef59066a8ac0e909#file-awaitmessages-go-L40): Considering that the messages may generate race conditions, this lock is added to ensure security
   - It can [generate filters](https://gist.github.com/CarsonSlovoka/395ec4218aa406d1ef59066a8ac0e909#file-awaitmessages-go-L101-L154): to communicate with each filter, we need to [provide a chan for each filter.](https://gist.github.com/CarsonSlovoka/395ec4218aa406d1ef59066a8ac0e909#file-awaitmessages-go-L39)
2. Whenever a new message is created, [we add the message to the message center](https://gist.github.com/CarsonSlovoka/395ec4218aa406d1ef59066a8ac0e909#file-awaitmessages-go-L172), and it also [notifies each filter](https://gist.github.com/CarsonSlovoka/395ec4218aa406d1ef59066a8ac0e909#file-awaitmessages-go-L59).
3. Define your [filter function](https://gist.github.com/CarsonSlovoka/395ec4218aa406d1ef59066a8ac0e909#file-awaitmessages-go-L103): The message will be collected whenever this criterion is true. for [example](https://gist.github.com/CarsonSlovoka/395ec4218aa406d1ef59066a8ac0e909#file-awaitmessages-go-L206-L209)
4. Define the [callback function](https://gist.github.com/CarsonSlovoka/395ec4218aa406d1ef59066a8ac0e909#file-awaitmessages-go-L107): This is the result of the filter function. You can do something based on this result. for [example](https://gist.github.com/CarsonSlovoka/395ec4218aa406d1ef59066a8ac0e909#file-awaitmessages-go-L181-L202)

### Full code

I put the full code on the [replit](https://replit.com/@jackparadise520/awaitMessages#main.go) and [gist](https://gist.github.com/CarsonSlovoka/395ec4218aa406d1ef59066a8ac0e909#file-awaitmessages-go).
If you want to run it, you can copy the code from replit and [set your token and channel ID (or user ID)](https://gist.github.com/CarsonSlovoka/395ec4218aa406d1ef59066a8ac0e909#file-awaitmessages-go-L28-L29) in the environment variables to test it.